# How to build a Machine Learning Model for Forecasting under a constraint?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, dataset

I have a **Dataset** of daily ATM demand, and i'll build a **Machine Learning Model** based on **Neural network** to generate the **ATM's cash demand forecasting** of the next month to know when we will have the next ATM replenishment. but the plus is that i want to generate this replenishment forecast **under a constraint** which is:

- Use all the replenishments per month exist in the policy signed by the bank with the money transportation company or the cash center, or minimizing the extras replenishments, if there is an over demand.

I want to know if there is a solution for this Machine Learning problem?
Thank youu

Comment: Did you try any traditional time series forecasting methods? Why ML?

Comment: The forecasted demand is related to many features so the Neural Networks is a good solution i think, actualy i didn't try any traditional method.

Comment: Do you have enough data? Something like demand for ATM is unlikely to produce troves of data, in my opinion. You need a benchmark anyways, so build it with traditional time series forecast, then even if it's not so good you'll be able to compare it to ML solution later.

Answer (score 1):

As @Aksakal writes, try a traditional time series forecasting algorithm first. Cash withdrawals will definitely have a weekly seasonality, so try seasonal exponential smoothing. You *may* have monthly seasonality, in which case you could use [bats](/questions/tagged/bats) or [tbats](/questions/tagged/tbats) to model the [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities).

If you have external drivers, like festivals, you can first regress withdrawals on these drivers, then model residuals with smoothing, BATS or TBATS. This would be similar to regression with ARIMA errors.

Your "constraint" is unclear to me. However, it sounds like you are conflating the *forecast* with the subsequent *decision*, i.e., with how much cash to supply the machine. Separate the two. First calculate your forecast, then make the decision based on the forecast.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the constraints which you wish to include in your prediction as parameters to your model. For eg: if you wish to minimize the replenishment if your demand is high, add a parameter for the same and when you are training models make sure your ground truth has a predicted less replenishment when there is high demand.